# Facing error Conflicting data type but cannot find any conflict

Tags: c

I have declared a function in file_utils.h and defined it in file_utils.c At compile time it is gives a conflicting type error.

File_utils.h

```
    #ifndef FILE_UTILS_H
    #define FILE_UTILS_H

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdint.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdbool.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>

    #ifdef HAVE_DIRENT_H
    #include <dirent.h>
    #define NAMLEN(dirent) strlen((dirent)->d_name)

    #else

    #define dirent direct
    #define NAMLEN(dirent) ((dirent)->d_namlen)
    #ifdef HAVE_SYS_NDIR_H
    #include <sys/ndir.h>
    #endif

    #ifdef HAVE_SYS_DIR_H
    #include <sys/dir.h>
    #endif

    #ifdef HAVE_NDIR_H
    #include <ndir.h>
    #endif

    #endif


    bool is_relative_path(struct dirent *ent);
```

File_utils.c

```
    #include "file_utils.h"
    #include <stdbool.h>
    #include <dirent.h>

    bool is_relative_path(struct dirent *ent){
        return (strcmp(ent->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(ent->d_name, "..") == 0);
     }
```

Error:

```
abhiram@abhiram-Lenovo-G50-70:~/libpostal-master/src$ gcc -DLIBPOSTAL_DATA_DIR='"$//home/abhiram/libpostal-master/data"' -o main main.c libpostal.c file_utils.c json_encode.c string_utils.c -std=c99 -w     
file_utils.c:45:6: error: conflicting types for ‘is_relative_path’
bool is_relative_path(struct dirent *ent){
     ^
In file included from file_utils.c:1:0:
file_utils.h:59:6: note: previous declaration of ‘is_relative_path’ was here
bool is_relative_path(struct dirent *ent);
     ^
```

I have included both dirent.h and stdbool.h libraries.

Comment: Your last comment speaks of file "dirent.h", while the whole rest of the question as well as the debug output speak of "file_utils.c" and "file_utils.h". Are the perhaps conflicting definitions of what a `struct dirent` is in these 3 files?

Comment: @GuntherSchulz I have included all the directives about dirent the code contains there is no other struct defined by me as such.

Comment: @Abhiram check my full answer below

Answer (score 2):

1. Resolve all compiler warnings.
2. Compile with all compiler warnings enabled `-Wall -Wextra`.
3. Resolve all compiler warnings.
4. The code you posted has a missing `#endif`, maybe probably from `#ifdef HAVE_DIRENT_H`, but I am guessing the last line of the `file_utils.h` should be a closing `#endif`.
5. The warning I get from gcc is this:

> warning: ‘struct direct’ declared inside parameter list
>   warning: its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want

This is the the most important warning.

Structure definition is only valid inside function parameter list. Ex:

```
void other_f(
   struct B a // this will forward declare struct B
   // scope of this variable is _only_ inside function parameter list
); // here struct B get's out of scope!
struct B b; // will error, there is no struct B here
// struct B was declared inside function parameter list
// you can't use it anywhere else
```

The MCVE to your problem would be this example:

```
void f(struct A);
struct A;
void f(struct A); // error conflicting types for 'f'
```

The `struct A` will be declared (I call it "auto-declared") inside the function parameter list `void f( <here> )` on the first use. The structure declaration will be visible only inside the parameter list. So it's similar to a pseudocode:

```
{
   struct A; // type only valid inside `{` `}` braces
   void f(struct A a); // imagine this symbol is visible outside `{` `}`
}
```

ie. the `struct A` is not visible outside the `{` `}`.

Then you declare another `struct A`:

```
struct A;
void f(struct A a);
```

But this `struct A` is different type as the other `struct A`. As it's different `struct A`, the function `f` is different, the compiler issues an error.

No consider your header:

```
#define dirent direct
...
bool is_relative_path(struct dirent *ent);
```

I don't know if `direct` is a typo or not. But you need to forward declare the `struct direct`, so that the forward declaration of struct direct is visible outside the function parameter list of `is_relative_path` function.

```
struct direct;
#define dirent direct
...
// or here:
struct dirent;
bool is_relative_path(struct dirent *ent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be file inclusion order if `"File_utils.c"` and / or a missing definition of `HAVE_DIRENT_H`.

In the given inclusion order, `"file_utils.h"` has no idea what a `struct dirent` is, since (presumably `HAVE_DIRENT_H`) is defined within `<dirent.h>`. If this is NOT the case, simply ensure that `HAVE_DIRENT_H` IS defined before including `"file_utils.h"`

The net effect as-is in the code is that in `"file_utils.h"`, `bool is_relative_path(struct dirent *ent)` is actually seen as `bool is_relative_path(some_pointer_to_an_unknown_struct_type ent)`, while the `"file_utils.c"` sees the function signature as as `bool is_relative_path(a_pointer_to_a_struct_type_i_definately_know_about ent)`.

Thus the two files do NOT agree on the function signature.

**Edit**

@n.m. is correct in that `"file_utils.h"` essentially sees a distinct definition of `struct dirent`, and that one cannot declare a type inside a function parameter list.

**TLDR**

Edit File_utils.c to define `HAVE_DIRENT_H` and / or `#include <dirent.h>` **before** `#include "file_utils.h"` so that both `"file_utils.h"` and `"file_utils.c"` see a common function signature for `bool is_relative_path(struct dirent *ent)`

Comment: adding the `HAVE_DIRENT_H` in the file_utils.c didn't work it throws the same error and `#include<dirent.h>` before `"file_utils.h"` throws previous error and also gives a error `file_utils.c: In function ‘is_relative_path’:
file_utils.c:70:20: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
  return (strcmp(ent->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(ent->d_name, "..") == 0);
                    ^
file_utils.c:70:53: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
  return (strcmp(ent->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(ent->d_name, "..") == 0);
                                                     ^
`

Comment: @Abhiram, "dereferencing pointer to incomplete type" typically happens when you misspell the destination type of a pointer, and then try and dereference the pointer to that misspelled type. **Check carefully** for typos on `struct dirent` usage

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the declaration of `bool is_relative_path(struct dirent *ent);` is AFTER the `#endif` preprocessor declaration (include guards). That mean including this header file in two different files will cause two declarations. Have a look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard to get some more details

This should fix it:

```
#ifndef FILE_UTILS_H
#define FILE_UTILS_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#ifdef HAVE_DIRENT_H
#include <dirent.h>
#define NAMLEN(dirent) strlen((dirent)->d_name)

#else

#define dirent direct
#define NAMLEN(dirent) ((dirent)->d_namlen)
#ifdef HAVE_SYS_NDIR_H
#include <sys/ndir.h>
#endif

#ifdef HAVE_SYS_DIR_H
#include <sys/dir.h>
#endif

#ifdef HAVE_NDIR_H
#include <ndir.h>
#endif

// moved the declaration between the #ifndef #endif block
bool is_relative_path(struct dirent *ent);

#endif
```

Comment: But you can have as many repeated same declarations as you want. You have a missing `#endif`.

Comment: @KamilCuk is correct in that repeated declarations are allowed. This is NOT the issue. See my full answer above

Comment: Got your point. I missed this one. Sounds like a bad idea to have the  `    #include <dirent.h>` at the c file right?

Comment: I tried moving the declaration as you suggested it still gives the same error of conflicting type

Answer (score 0):

You cannot declare a type inside a function parameter list. This is what happens when in File_utils.h you have a declaration of  `is_relative_path` with no prior declaration of `stuct dirent`.

Either `#include <dirent.h>` in File_utils.h (recommended), or add a declaration

```
struct dirent;
```

somewhere in it above `is_relative_path`.